# Mutiple Sites on localhost root (xampp) /w absolute paths

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I have several projects on Linux-Servers which I work on locally with my Windows xampp enviroment.
However, the apache directory (Virtual Host) settings are like this on all projects:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/web
<Directory /var/www/html/project1/web/>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</Directory>
```

Now I can use absolute paths in my source such as `/images/`

When I create a Directory in the xampp httpd.conf like this, it works, but only for the project I have the document root specified for:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/web"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/web">
....
</Directory>
```

I would like to work on `project2` as well but I also want the `/images/` path to work in p2 as well, so changing the `DocumentRoot` to `htdocs` does not work. I also tried `Alias` but to no avail.

Where am I wrong, how do other people work on multiple projects, do they update the https.conf every time the switch projects?

Answer (score 0):

have nothing to test here but you could edit your *hosts* to something like:

127.0.0.1 localhost
 127.0.0.1 foo.localhost
 127.0.0.1 bar.localhost

Once you're done, you should be able to create multiple Virtualhosts with different paths